# Find bad word in an Array in a file , then replace it by ***

Tags: ruby

i am a newbie in ruby , 
i hava an array of bad words, so i want to test a file, if find a bad word then replace it by ***

```
class BadWord
  def changeword
    bad_word = [ "badword1", "badword2", "badword3", "badword4" ]
    data = File.read("script.txt")
    filterdata = bad_word.map{|item|
    data.gsub("#{item}","***")
    File.write("script.txt",filterdata)
  end
end
obj = BadWord.new()
obj.changeword()
```

Comment: So, what is wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Your code is kind of rude. You could make your `bad_word = ["bad_word1", "bad_word2", "bad_word3"]` and everybody would understand you.

Comment: And … what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
class BadWordsFilter < Struct(:filename)
  attr_reader :filename

  BAD_WORDS   = w%[badword1 badword2 badword3 badword4]
  WORD_REGEXP = Regexp.union(BAD_WORDS)

  def sanitize
    content  = File.read(filename)
    filtered = content.gsub(WORD_REGEXP, '***')

    File.write(filename, filtered)
  end
end

filter = BadWordsFilter.new('script.txt')
filter.sanitize
```